# Django IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint ... DETAIL: Key ... already exists

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In a Django app with Postgres db i have a model named Block. It is used in other models as ForeignKey

```
class Block(models.Model):
    name = TranslatedField(models.CharField(max_length=200),)
    color = models.IntegerField(choices=BLOCKCOLOR_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    blocktype = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BLOCKTYPE_CHOICES, default="break")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.blocktype})"
```

I use django-translated-fields to translate the name in 4 languages. These are the relevant lines in admin:

```
class BlockAdmin(TranslatedFieldAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Block, BlockAdmin)
```

I can create a new instance of Block in the admin interface and also in the view.

When I edit the model and try to save I get the above mentioned error. It happens in the admin interface and in the view as well. I can manually delete the model and create a new one, it gets a new id.

It doesn't matter if the model is already bound via ForeignKey to another model or if it's standalone.

Can somebody give me an advice? Thank you in advance!

I have tried manipulating the id in the database, as a final solution I have also deleted the database completely. It happens again. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the django-translated-fields package.

Here is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1889, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/translated_fields/admin.py", line 19, in changeform_view
    response = super().changeform_view(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1747, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1798, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1227, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/mealscode/main/models.py", line 122, in save
    return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/config/workspace/mealscode/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "main_block_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(8) already exists.
```

Comment: Please format your traceback as "code". It is hard to read like this.

Comment: Could it have something to do with  ATOMIC_REQUESTS or autocommit?

Comment: ATOMIC_REQUESTS is not set to True. Autocommit is not turned on.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with this piece of code in the Model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.name.capitalize()
    return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I wanted to capitalize user input when the instance is saved but somehow this caused the problem. I will capitalize the input in the view and save it that was in the field.